# Landscape video from portrait images using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a series of pictures taken in portrait mode with a resolution of 480x800. I made video using ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -r 1 -y -i image%d.jpeg out.mp4` And I get video in landscape mode with a resolution 480x800 and 4:3, and therefore the image of video is stretched laterally. How to make that video is not stretched and the sides were black stripes?

Log

```
 ffmpeg version N-56554-ge07ac72 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Oct 23 2013 21:24:32 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC)
    ffmpeg4android: 1.1.03 
      libavutil      52. 45.100 / 52. 45.100
      libavcodec     55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
      libavformat    55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
      libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
      libavfilter     3. 86.102 /  3. 86.102
      libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
      libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
      libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
    Splitting the commandline.
    Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '1'.
    Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
    Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/sdcard/videokit/i%d.jpeg'.
    Reading option '/sdcard/videokit/scr.mp4' ... matched as output file.
    Finished splitting the commandline.
    Parsing a group of options: global .
    Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Parsing a group of options: input file /sdcard/videokit/i%d.jpeg.
    Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 1.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an input file: /sdcard/videokit/i%d.jpeg.
    Statistics: 298974 bytes read, 0 seeks
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=298972
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=298970
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=298952
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=298883
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=298814
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298795
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298762
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298579
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298546
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 2590 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=298363
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 295772 bytes (2366171 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    Statistics: 76534 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 154535 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 199474 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 200272 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 200805 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 201336 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 201897 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 201869 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 200555 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 202662 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 203348 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 203689 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 204322 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 204731 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 205169 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 205779 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Statistics: 204628 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Input #0, image2, from '/sdcard/videokit/i%d.jpeg':
      Duration: 00:00:00.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0, 18, 1/25: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 480x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:5], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Successfully opened the file.
    Parsing a group of options: output file /sdcard/videokit/scr.mp4.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an output file: /sdcard/videokit/scr.mp4.
    Successfully opened the file.
    detected 2 logical cores
    Setting 'video_size' to value '480x800'
    Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '12'
    Setting 'time_base' to value '1/1'
    Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
    Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
    Setting 'frame_rate' to value '1/1'
    w:480 h:800 pixfmt:yuvj420p tb:1/1 fr:1/1 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
    Setting 'expr' to value 'N'
    compat: called with args=[yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p]
    Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p'
    query_formats: 5 queried, 4 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
    TB:1.000000 FRAME_RATE:1.000000 SAMPLE_RATE:NaN
    No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
    Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
    using SAR=1/1
    using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
    profile High, level 2.2
    264 - core 125 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to '/sdcard/videokit/scr.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf55.18.102
        Stream #0:0, 0, 1/16384: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 480x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:5], q=-1--1, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=298972
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=298970
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=298952
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=298883
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=298814
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298795
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298762
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298579
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=298546
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 2590 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=298363
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 295772 bytes (2366171 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:0 PTS:0 T:0.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:0 T:0.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=76532
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=76530
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=76512
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=76443
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=76374
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=76355
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=76322
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=76139
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=76106
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 1467 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=75923
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 74455 bytes (595639 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:1 PTS:1 T:1.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:1 T:1.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=154533
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=154531
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=154513
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=154444
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=154375
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=154356
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=154323
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=154140
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=154107
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 2539 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=153924
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 151384 bytes (1211070 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:2 PTS:2 T:2.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:2 T:2.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=199472
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=199470
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=199452
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=199383
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=199314
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199295
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199262
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199079
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199046
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 3374 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=198863
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 195488 bytes (1563900 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:3 PTS:3 T:3.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:3 T:3.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=200270
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=200268
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=200250
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=200181
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=200112
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200093
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200060
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199877
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=199844
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 3450 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=199661
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 196210 bytes (1569680 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:4 PTS:4 T:4.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:4 T:4.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=200803
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=200801
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=200783
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=200714
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=200645
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200626
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200593
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200410
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200377
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 3447 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=200194
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 196746 bytes (1573962 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:5 PTS:5 T:5.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:5 T:5.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=201334
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=201332
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=201314
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=201245
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=201176
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=201157
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=201124
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=200941
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
   .....
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=205600
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=205567
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=205384
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=205351
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 3602 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=205168
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 201565 bytes (1612516 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:16 PTS:16 T:16.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:16 T:16.000000
    marker=d8 avail_size_in_buf=204626
    marker parser used 0 bytes (0 bits)
    marker=e0 avail_size_in_buf=204624
    marker parser used 16 bytes (128 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=204606
    index=0
    qscale[0]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=db avail_size_in_buf=204537
    index=1
    qscale[1]: 0
    marker parser used 67 bytes (536 bits)
    marker=c0 avail_size_in_buf=204468
    sof0: picture: 480x800
    component 0 2:2 id: 0 quant:0
    component 1 1:1 id: 1 quant:1
    component 2 1:1 id: 2 quant:1
    pix fmt id 22111100
    marker parser used 17 bytes (136 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=204449
    class=0 index=0 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=204416
    class=1 index=0 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=204233
    class=0 index=1 nb_codes=12
    marker parser used 31 bytes (248 bits)
    marker=c4 avail_size_in_buf=204200
    class=1 index=1 nb_codes=251
    marker parser used 181 bytes (1448 bits)
    escaping removed 3751 bytes
    marker=da avail_size_in_buf=204017
    component: 0
    component: 1
    component: 2
    marker parser used 200265 bytes (1602113 bits)
    marker=d9 avail_size_in_buf=0
    decode frame unused 0 bytes
    N:17 PTS:17 T:17.000000 POS:nan INTERLACED:0 -> PTS:17 T:17.000000
    frame=   18 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
    EOF on sink link output stream 0:0:default.
    No more output streams to write to, finishing.
    frame=   0 QP=18.27 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:1500 P:0    SKIP:0    size=79447 bytes
    frame=   1 QP=17.68 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:1442 P:3    SKIP:55   size=16738 bytes
    frame=   2 QP=17.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:1438 P:12   SKIP:50   size=34918 bytes
    scene cut at 3 Icost:1316705 Pcost:1231427 ratio:0.0648 bias:0.1024 gop:3 (imb:1247 pmb:97)
    frame=   3 QP=9.48 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:1500 P:0    SKIP:0    size=100475 bytes
    frame=   4 QP=12.94 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:3    P:31   SKIP:1466 size=464 bytes
    frame=   5 QP=16.31 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:8    P:8    SKIP:1484 size=422 bytes
    frame=   6 QP=14.33 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:10  I:6    P:26   SKIP:1468 size=899 bytes
    frame=   7 QP=17.58 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:8   I:1    P:20   SKIP:1478 size=159 bytes
    frame=   8 QP=19.96 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:6   I:0    P:28   SKIP:1472 size=129 bytes
    frame=   9 QP=14.80 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:18  I:8    P:15   SKIP:1477 size=762 bytes
    frame=  10 QP=20.28 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:14  I:0    P:22   SKIP:1477 size=108 bytes
    frame=  11 QP=18.18 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:12  I:132  P:277  SKIP:1054 size=7450 bytes
    frame=  12 QP=19.95 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:16  I:0    P:24   SKIP:1475 size=151 bytes
    frame=  13 QP=19.55 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:26  I:10   P:10   SKIP:1480 size=952 bytes
    frame=  14 QP=19.94 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:22  I:0    P:30   SKIP:1470 size=171 bytes
    frame=  15 QP=19.98 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:20  I:0    P:26   SKIP:1474 size=138 bytes
    frame=  16 QP=19.93 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:24  I:1    P:23   SKIP:1476 size=146 bytes
    frame=  17 QP=18.70 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:28  I:159  P:260  SKIP:1081 size=7512 bytes
    frame=   18 fps=4.6 q=17.0 Lsize=     247kB time=00:00:16.00 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s    
    video:246kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.388076%
    frame I:2     Avg QP:13.87  size: 89961
    frame P:8     Avg QP:16.41  size:  7833
    frame B:8     Avg QP:19.48  size:  1056
    consecutive B-frames: 38.9%  0.0% 16.7% 44.4%
    mb I  I16..4: 17.5% 26.8% 55.7%
    mb P  I16..4: 16.1%  1.3%  8.2%  P16..4:  1.6%  1.0%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:71.3%
    mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.1%  0.7%  B16..8:  2.3%  1.4%  0.3%  direct: 0.1%  skip:94.8%  L0:53.7% L1:46.0% BI: 0.3%
    8x8 transform intra:15.6% inter:40.1%
    coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 53.6% 33.8% 27.4% inter: 0.6% 0.0% 0.0%
    i16 v,h,dc,p: 65% 33%  2%  1%
    i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  6% 62% 12%  4%  3%  3%  3%  2%  5%
    i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 34% 13%  5%  5%  5%  5%  4%  5%
    i8c dc,h,v,p: 69% 19% 10%  2%
    Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
    ref P L0: 79.9%  3.8% 14.9%  1.4%
    ref B L0: 97.3%  1.5%  1.1%
    ref B L1: 82.0% 18.0%
    kb/s:111.57
    18 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
    Statistics: 34 seeks, 50 writeouts
```

Comment: What players are you using to view the resulting video?

Comment: in the console output it's saying that the output movie is 480x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:5], which is the same as your input. It could be that the player is refusing to play the video correctly.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm using standard Android player

Comment: @stib Yes, you are right! I watched the video through a lot of players on PC and on smartphone, and only one of them displayed it correctly. Please, post your comment as answer, and I will accept it. Thanks to you and to LordNeckbread!

Comment: In KMP Player I set "preserve the original aspect ratio" and than all good!